# Why the maximum value of byte plus one, but there is no overflow

Tags: java, byte, overflow

```
class Overflowtest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte maxValue= Byte.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println("maxValue of byte is "+maxValue);
    System.out.println("add 1 to maxValue of byte is "+maxValue+(byte)2);

  }
}
```

Why there is no overflow happened when I try `maxValue+(byte)2`?
But if I did this, `(byte)(maxValue+2)`, overflow happened.

Comment: you just adding some values. but not assigning to any `byte` type.

Comment: You wrote + in title and doing + 2 in code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you're adding 127 to a string and then adding 2 to a string.

But when you do:

```
System.out.println(maxValue+(byte)2);
```

Binary operation return a integer number.

Comment: @Doris `but the example is System.out.println("add 2 to maxValue of int is "+(maxValue+2)); and the output is overflow` That means, the author is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that you are first concatenating the 127 to the string, then concatenating the 2. So the value you see is actually "1272".

But when you put `(maxValue + (byte)2)` in paretheses, you have another issue: the `+` operator causes **Binary Numeric Promotion**. This is mentioned in the [Java Language Specification, item 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>      conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>      both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

This is followed by the list of operators that cause such Binary Numeric Promotion, and it includes the operator `+`.

So you see, both operands are converted to `int`. And become just `127 + 2`, which does not overflow the `int` range. The result is an `int`.

To see an actual overflow, you may want to do something like:

```
byte newValue = (byte) (maxValue + (byte)2); // Notice that you can't assign it without the cast!
System.out.println(newValue);
```

This overflow doesn't actually occur as a result of adding 2, but as a result of truncating the integer `129` and taking only its rightmost byte.

Answer (score 2):

As others stated after you resolve your parenthesis you are able to print the value

```
System.out.println("add 1 to maxValue of byte is "
                + (maxValue + ((byte) 2)));
```

Which gives you output 129.

The reason for that is here whats happening is `Integer addition`. Not byte assignment. So you are not seeing any exception.

When you are adding your byte casted value to `maxValue` that immediately turning as a integer addition.

To check your actual question try to do

```
byte maxValue2 =(maxValue + ((byte) 2));
```

That won't compile since the resultant is an int. So when you change your code to

```
int  maxValue2 = maxValue + ((byte) 2);
```

That works.

Again now coming to your old interpretation when you do byte assignment with help of casting the result to byte

```
byte maxValue2 = (byte) (maxValue + ((byte) 2));
```

Now you see the overflow silently and  truncates higher order bits of integer and results yout maxValue2 to `-127`.